Build fail to compile due to Unexpected end of JSON input
I have an issue when trying to build my react app.
This works perfectly in a dev environement using npm start however once I try to build it I have this error.
> my-react-app@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Unexpected end of JSON input


I have added a console log to verify that my environment variables are correctly replaced in dev environment however those are not fetch correctly during the build.
My .env is at the root directory of my application and all my variable starts with REACT_APP_*
The code of the login page I am trying to build
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"; // Import signInWithEmailAndPassword
import { auth } from "./firebase"; // Import Firebase auth instance

function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!email || !password) {
      setError("Email and password are required.");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      console.log("User signed in:", userCredential.user);
      alert("Login successful!");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error during login:", err.message);
      setError("Login failed: " + err.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Password:</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </div>
        {error && <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</p>}
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;

Thanks

"When I remove firebase" - please edit the question to be clear exactly what you're doing that make things work. We should be able to do the exact same thing and achieve the same result.

I fixed this issue on a Mac OS by upgrading the version of Node, I just ran the following command
brew upgrade node


tried this, I am already using node v23.2.0 and it's still blocked

Can you also try running npm cache clean —force ?

The error Unexpected end of JSON input during the build process,normally occurs with a issue in environment variables or Firebase configuration not being correctly set or accessible during the build.

Ensure all Firebase-related environment variables are correctly
defined in your .env file.
Make sure that your firebase initialization is correctly implemented.


That's what I have in mind.
I've checked that my .env is at the root
I've checked that everything is format this way REACT_APP_*=
I've added a console log console.log("API Key from ENV:", process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY); and I see that it works well after a npm start
I have added '    "prebuild": "echo REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY=$REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY",' in my package .json and this is empty.
I don't understand why the .env isn't fetch correctly during the build

Did you check your firebase initialization.

I initialize it this way in my firebase-config.js
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default app;

So I completely uninstall Node that was previously installed using nvm and reinstall it using brew and it works.
